# Altair can't access filesystem to render large datasets on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, altair

I'm trying to generate a large number of plots from a single large dataset using Altair on Google Colab. To improve performance, I would like to implement one of the solutions recommended [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html#maxrowserror-how-can-i-plot-large-datasets). However, so far none have been successful. Ideally I would like to use the json data_transformer, but this leads to 404 and 500 errors as pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biqlj.png). Is there any way I can serve these files to enable the desired behavior?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What specifically have you tried? It's critical to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you specifically tried for debugging/testing. For more help see, [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned at https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html#maxrowserror-how-can-i-plot-large-datasets, the json transformer will not work on cloud-based Jupyter environments.

For Colab, the easiest approach to solving your problem is to use `altair_data_server`. Just run the following:

```py
!pip install altair_data_server
alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')
```

(NB: `'data_server_proxied'` *does not* work in Colab, but `'data_server'` does).

For more information, see the `altair_data_server` Colab example notebook at https://colab.research.google.com/github/altair-viz/altair_data_server/blob/master/AltairDataServer.ipynb

Comment: Thanks! This does work. Interestingly I often have to run the cell twice to get the data to display; the first time it runs a new plot it often generates a blank cell. This might also be a latency issue I suppose.

Comment: You only have to enable the data transformer once per notebook, not once per cell.

Comment: I have the same issue as @Chain_Reaktion with [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Roald87/CoronaWeather/blob/master/CoronaWeather_colab.ipynb#) notebook and I just enable the data transformer once.